# Listing products function for users with WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a one simple question - is it real to create function which allows to users list their own products on my website, with Word Press and WooCommerce plugin ? Can you share solutions if is ?
Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$args = get_posts( [
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'post_status'    => [ 'publish', 'pending' ],
    'author'         => get_current_user_id(),
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'page'           => 1,
    'offset'         => 0,
    'orderby'        => 'post_date',
    'order'          => 'desc',
 ] );
```